# Can't install Nautilus in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, 16.04

Due to some drop-box problem I removed Nautilus without seeing what  this app is . Now I can't open any file , Home button is completely removed , all the desktop items have gone . I can't install it ,

"$sudo apt-get install nautilus" is not working

errors are prompting . I am attaching a screen-shot . What to do ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like postfix is failing.  I don't know your setup or postfix.
You could remove postfix, then install nautilus, then install postfix again (or attempt to).